# Flutter Localize Syncfusion Calender with GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, calendar, syncfusion

I am using the [Syncfusion Calender](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/calendar/overview) in my app. The problem is that I would like to localize it but I can not make it work... I checked there [documentation](https://www.syncfusion.com/kb/11246/how-to-localize-the-flutter-calendar), but the given example is working with the normal `MaterialApp`. I am using `GetX`, also for `Localization`.

How can I localize the calender with my `GetXApp`?

This is my `App`:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(
          create: (context) => DataProvider(),
        ),
      ],
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Boilerplate',
        navigatorKey: Get.key,
        translationsKeys: AppTranslation.translationsKeys,
        locale: locale,
        fallbackLocale: fallbackLocale,
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: AppTextStyles.montserrat,
          primarySwatch: ColorService.createMaterialColor(
            AppColors.blue,
          ),
          backgroundColor: AppColors.white,
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: AppColors.white,
        ),
        initialRoute: Views.home,
        onGenerateRoute: AppRouter.generateRoute,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Couldn't find anything on this... Every help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the provided information we have analyzed your requirement **“How to add localization of syncfusion flutter calendar by using GetX“** and you can achieve your requirement by adding `localizationsDelegates` and `supportedLocales` in the GetMaterialApp. We have modified the shared sample based on your requirement.

Kindly find the sample by referring to the following link:
https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/locale_with_getx-1984841410

Regards,

Muthulakshmi

Comment: working as expected! Thanks for your help :)